# Dynamic Pivot Sql for matrix report

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

This is the static pivot SQL query.

```
WITH 
   T 
AS 
(
   SELECT 
      DEPTNO 
   FROM 
      EMP
)
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   T
PIVOT 
(
   COUNT(*) 
   FOR 
      (DEPTNO) 
   IN 
      (10,20,30,40)
```

But I want to dynamic SQL query for matrix report. where heading name will be department name not department id. So what can I do now?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 Sample output or data should also be shown as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). You can use tools [like this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) or [this](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) to generate nice tables. To learn hot to format plain text properly please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362).

Comment: Yes i understand about tag. next time i never do that.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you .You need to give an alias as what is in your mind to the first select:

```
  SELECT 
      'empname' as empname ,[0] as yourdepartname1, [1] as yourdepartname2, [2] as yourdepartname2, [3]yourdepartname4, [4] as yourdepartname5
   FROM 
      (  
SELECT 
   empname,DEPTNO 
FROM 
   EMP e
inner join department d on d.DEPTNO on e.deptno
group by empname) p
    PIVOT 
    (
       COUNT(*) 
       FOR 
          (empname) 
       IN 
          ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4] ))
    AS PivotTable
```